# Properties of the Gaussian and Eisenstein Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying for an exam, and one of the practice questions is:

> Let $p \geq 5$ be a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $\langle p \rangle$ is not prime in the the Gaussian integers iff there is a solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The next step is to show the same statement for the Eisenstein integers, where instead of a solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$, that statement is for $x^2-x+1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

I'm very lost on how to go about this problem, but I think if I understood how to do the first part, I could apply it to figure out the second part.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p=\alpha \beta$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a factorization of the (regular) prime $p$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Then using the norm $N(a+ib)=a^2+b^2$, we get
$$N(p)=p^2=N(\alpha) \, N(\beta).$$
For a non-trivial factorization, $N(\alpha)=N(\beta)=p$. If $\alpha=x+iy$, then we want
$$x^2+y^2=0 \pmod{p}. \tag{1}$$
Since $y \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ (why?), so $\gcd(y,p)=1$ and as a result $y^{-1}$ exists. So (1) be rewritten as 
$$z^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p},$$
where $z=xy^{-1}$. I hope you can take it from here.